# Right/left align chapter number and center the chapter title on the next page

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I want to left or right align my chapter number, and center the chapter title on the next page. I've used the `\titlesec` package, but it removes the header and footer on the first page of every chapter.  The code I've written right aligns both the chapter number and the title. Is there any workaround?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedleft}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}{\Large}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{XYZ}

\lhead{year}

\lfoot{Blah}

\cfoot{}

\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you're interested in achieving 2 goals: (1) Headers/footers on your first page of chapter; and (2) a left/right alignment of chapter title+number. I'm not clear on exactly what (2) refers to. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If I'm having a chapter titled Introduction, and it is the first chapter, I'd like chapter 1 to be aligned to the left or right, and I'd like Introduction to be centered on the next line following the chapter number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the header/footer in the first page of every chapter, you can patch (with the help of, for example, `etoolbox` package) the `\chapter` command to change the default `plain` style for `fancy`.

To have the chapter name+chapter number right (left aligned) you can use `\filright` (`\filleft`, respectively) in the second argument for `\titleformat` and then `\filcenter` in the fifth argument to have the title centered;

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\filleft\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Large\filcenter}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{XYZ}
\fancyhead[L]{year}
\fancyfoot[L]{Blah}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Title}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the `geometry` package with its `showframe` option just to have a visual guideline.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!!